# Running Docker Image

Tags: linux, bash, docker, docker-for-mac

The [user guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockerizing/) states that an image should be run as follows:

```
docker run -t -i ubuntu /bin/bash
```

I get that `-t` creates the pseudo-terminal and `-i` makes it interactive. But it seems that the `/bin/bash` part is unnecessary. Whether I run it with or without `/bin/bash`, I'm given an interactive prompt that I can read and write from both times.

```
root@77eeb1f4ac2a:/#
```

Why do we need `/bin/bash`?

**Part 2**

I'm running on Docker for Mac. When I download the `hello-world` binary and run it, it's only `1kb`. Obviously a Linux image wasn't downloaded with it. Is the small `hello-world` binary running off my Mac kernel or off of a small Linux kernel that comes with Docker for Mac?

Comment: Here is more information about Part 2. Basically, hello-world is run "from scratch". https://hub.docker.com/_/hello-world/

Comment: @AlbertoRivera Thank you, but is a VM of Linux executing it or is my mac executing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do we need /bin/bash?

Because while the `ubuntu` image may be configured to run `/bin/bash` by default, that's not going to be true of every image.  If you have an image that starts a webserver by default, and you want to run `bash`...you need to make that explicit.  Some images don't specify any default command, leading to:

```
$ docker run -it alpine
docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified.
```

It never hurts to be explicit when starting a container, especially using an inmage that you didn't build yourself.

> When I download the hello-world binary and run it...

Which hello-world binary?

> but is a VM of Linux executing it or is my mac executing it?

Docker only runs under Linux.  When you are using Docker under OS X or Windows, you are running containers *inside* a Linux VM spawned for that purpose by `docker-machine` (or, previously, `boot2docker`).  Under Windows Docker uses Hyper V, and on OS X it previously used VirtualBox and in more recent versions may be using something else (it's been a while since I've run Docker under OS X).

Comment: Thank you. And I should have specified the [article](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_one/) for `hello-world`. So it is definitely some sort of Linux VM that is running the small `hello-world` binary? Someone also pointed out that it uses [osxfs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/) somehow.

Comment: `osxfs` is a mechanism for sharing files between your OS X host and the VM in which docker is running.  I think I have already answered the "is it a vm?" question, and I'm not sure what else I can say on that topic.

Answer (score 2):

Part 1:

Whatever you pass after `docker run -t -i ubuntu` is the first command that your container will run. You can try using /bin/bash, /bin/sh, or even `echo hello` and see it in action. Ubuntu uses bash by default, but other containers use other commands based on their Dockerfiles.

part 2:

When you run hello-world, a docker container is created from the hello-image. Containers "include the application and all of its dependencies --but share the kernel with other containers, running as isolated processes in user space on the host operating system.".

Hello-world in specific is created from scratch https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch/.